# What is an ok rate on unconfirmed emails?

Tags: registration, email, onboarding

We are running an online platform which requires a signup from the user. After completing the signup flow, the users is prompted to confirm her email. Without confirmation, the users can't use the platform.

Everyone can signup, only an email is required. The platform is for online volunteering for creatives from the spaces design, communication and tech. So I assume that every user has a goal while signing up.

Since the start 4 years ago we are monitoring a stable rate around 20% of the users which are never confirming their email (around 4% of the emails are bouncing). We thought hard about this and came to the conclusion that the 20% includes users

- which entered a fake email (why should a user do this?)
- made a spelling mistake
- doesn't have access to email account anymore (why should I use an email to which I don't have access?)
- signed up on mobile and doesn't have mobile email access, thus never finishing the sing up (are users really forgetting things so fast?)

In generell we are really unsure if 20% is ok and what the real reasons are. Anyone here to share some wisdom? :) Cheers, Lars

PS.: We once put a nice illustration on the confirmation page which decreased the bounce rate by 1,3% - yeah!

Comment: I think there are also the more obvious reasons like someone changing their mind or perhaps they were 'shopping' around for volunteering opportunities and didn't pick your option (for whatever reason). Do you see any patterns in this 20% that is different to the 80% to suggest that this is a higher number than you would expect?

Comment: The most likely reason for the fake emails being entered is spammers/bots trying to create fake accounts on your site to promote their wares. I would say that getting an 80% positive response rate is great!

Comment: I imagine there's no universal "ok rate." Is your current rate okay with you? (Apparently not.) Why not?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered offering access to the platform to everyone and only ask for registration after they want to perform a task that requires permanent storage in the DB? (Like saving their work or progress).

Giving a taste of the platform may result in more quality leads. Maybe your 20% con be reduced not by increasing number of users confirming emails, but by decreasing the number of poor quality ones.